# popToViewController with a specific UITabBarController Tab/View

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

I am using popToViewController method to pop to a view controller. What I was trying to achieve is to pop to an UITabBarController's specific index.

```
NSArray *viewArrays = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
```

So my view hierarchy is;

```
<LoginViewController: 0x6b75850>,
<UITabBarController: 0x6ba0b50>,
<RequestViewController: 0x684fe90>,
<ApplyViewController: 0x6845790>
```

Following code does pops to my UITabBarController, but since I was on the third view of my UITabBarController, it pops back to the third view

```
[[self navigationController] popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]  animated:YES];
```

What I want is to pop to the second view of my UITabBarController.

**Edit (Answer)**

As stated, we don't push or pop. So in order to gather your tabBarController you either use;

```
UITabBarController *myTabController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:indexOfYourTabBarControllerInYourNavigationController];
myTabController.selectedIndex = indexToGo;
```

or if you are on one of your tabBarController views;

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = indexToGo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UITabBarController you dont pop and push, if you want to go to the second view you would set the selected index instead

Like so

```
yourTabController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Or if the current view controller is a part of the tabBarController do

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: The second example can't work - selectedIndex is a `NSUInteger` property (and as such it can't be used as a `tabBarController`. Even if you'd use property `selectedViewController` you should typecast it to `TabBarController *` - and doing this you'd have to be certain that it really IS a `TabBarController`...

Comment: and how can I add my tabBarController to my current ViewController ? to use myTabcontroller.selectedIndex ? second one does not work as stated...

Comment: UITabBarController *myTabController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    myTabController.selectedIndex = 2;

this code segment doesn't seem to work to get my tabBarController, at least I cant set my selectedIndex

Comment: instead use UITabBarController *myTabController = self.tabBarController;

Comment: it does not work. Im not currently on my tabbarcontroller views, as you can see I am at ApplyViewController, which is index 3 on my navigationController stack, my TabBarController index is 1. Can i reach my tabTarcontroller with self.tabBarController ?

Comment: @Bartu please post some code on how you presented ApplyViewController

Comment: 4th comment of mine was working, I confused my index with 2, I should have been doing 1 instead. Thanks for your help sir.